# using .innerHTML in this way?

Tags: innerhtml

While studying JS, I saw this three lines:

```
var firstItem = document.getElementById('one');

var itemContent = firstItem.innerHTML;

firstItem.innerHTML = '<a href=\"http://example.org\">'+itemCotent+'</a>';
```

Can I just put .innerHTML in first line?
so that it becomes like this?

```
var firstItem = document.getElementById('one').innerHTML;

var itemContent = firstItem;

firstItem.innerHTML = '<a href=\"http://example.org\">'+itemContent+'</a>';
```

I am just new, so could anyone explain why if not? thank you.

Comment: no, firstItem is set to the innerHTML string in your second case

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably this?  Probably the best way to shorten it.
I've also added in [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax
You must set the property through a reference to an object, otherwise it will not affect the original object.  Your second example will just assign firstItem with the innerHTML string.

```js
var firstItem = document.getElementById('one');
firstItem.innerHTML = `http://example.org">${firstItem.innerHTML}`;
//firstItem.innerHTML = 'http://example.org\">'+firstItem.innerHTML+'';
```

```html
<div id="one">blahblah</div>
```

Comment: oh! you gave me 'ah' moment. oh thank you! I didn't think that way. thank you very much!!!

Comment: if the answer helped you, you can accept it as the solution

Comment: it was my first step putting in stackoverflow and you taught me things.  thank you!